# How to detect doubleClick in QTableView

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt

I'm using PyQt to create a GUI application. In a view inherited from QTableView, need to detect the row the user has selected when they double click a row. The table has sorting, but no editing.

How do I do it?

Note - tried the doubleClicked(int) signal. It is emitted by mouse buttons, not by data cells, so it was never fired. :(

Ian

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I dont understand.
The doubleClicked signal of the QTableView has the signature

```
void doubleClicked ( const QModelIndex & index )
```

If you connect that signal you should obtain the correct QModelIndex.

Comment: I tried both self.connect(self.tableView,SIGNAL("doubleClicked()"), self.dblClickHandler)  and self.connect(self.tableView,SIGNAL("doubleClicked(int)"), self.dblClickHandler)  - from examples of clicked. Also tried clicked(), and  mouseDoubleClickEvent(). None were triggered

Comment: I have never tried the python bindings, but you could try
self.connect(self.tableView,SIGNAL("doubleClicked(const QModelIndex&)"), self.dblClickHandler)

Comment: If const type& is an address (I don't know c++ well) then that is what the doubleClicked(int) version is.

Comment: no, the signals are connected by a string identifier. Hence the quotes in the SIGNAL()

Comment: It should be 'doubleClicked(QModelIndex)'.

Comment: Thank you Frank! The event is being called! It appears to be passing in the reciever of the signal (a CompanyListView, not a QModelIndex, but no matter. I can hack round that.

Comment: My bad - I'd missed the self param out!

Comment: Once you have the modelIndex, you can use it to find which cell was clicked.  
def slotDoubleClicked(self, mi):
    row = mi.row()
    column = mi.column()
You then need to use these row and col indices to access the table with table.setItem(row, column, newdata) or other table method

Answer (score 14):

No need to use SIGNALs anymore:

```
self.your_table.doubleClicked.connect(your_function)
```

"doubleClicked" being inherited from QAbstractItemView.

Comment: I know that this thread is a bit old, but as I am doing something similar, how do I go about getting the value within a particular cell that I have double-clicked on it?

Answer (score 5):

Once you have the modelIndex, (from Frank's comment above)  you can use it to find which cell was double clicked.

```
def slotDoubleClicked(self, mi):
    row = mi.row()
    column = mi.column()
```

You then can use these row and col values to access the table with table.setItem(row, column, newdata) or other table method

Answer (score 3):

Like @regomodo said, you can simply connect your function to the double click via:

```
self.your_table.doubleClicked.connect(your_function)
```

Then, if you want to know on which row the user double clicked, you can use the following code:

```
for idx in self.your_table.selectionModel().selectedIndexes():
        row_number = idx.row()
        column_number = idx.column()
```

It will return an integer corresponding to the row or the column number.
There will always only be a single value as the double click remove the previous selection.

If you link your function to a push button or another signal, you can receive a list containing multiple elements selected by the user.

For example, you can easily retrieve a list of all selected rows using this code:

```
rows = []
for idx in self.your_table.selectionModel().selectedIndexes():
    rows.append(idx.row())
rows = list(set(rows))
```

This will return a list of all selected rows (The set function will also remove any duplicates).

Cheers!

Comment: If sorting is enabled, your data in the model will be reordered and you may not get actual data, no?