# Get double click on line with pyqt5 QTableView

Tags: pyqt5, signals, python-3.6, qtableview, double-click

I'm doing my first steps with pyqt5. I just want to create window with a list showing the content of a csv file. I expected this to be quite simple... I want to add an action when the user makes a double clic on a line of my table. Currently I use QAbstractTableModel -> QTableView -> QWidget

Here some piece of code :

```
class TableViewModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, str_report_path, parent=None):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.generate_data(str_report_path)

    def data(self, index, role):
        data = None
        i_column = None
        i_row = None

        if index.isValid():
            i_column = index.column()
            i_row = index.row()
            ...
            return data

    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        b_well_done = False
        if index.isValid():
            b_well_done = True
            i_column = index.column()
            i_row = index.row()
            ...

   def flags(self, index):
        fl = QAbstractTableModel.flags(self, index)
        i_column = index.column()
        i_row = index.row()
        ...
        return fl



class TableWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, str_path_to_report, str_ref_path, str_ope_path, *args):
        #creation du tableau
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args)
        self.str_ref_path = str_ref_path
        self.str_ope_path = str_ope_path
        self.d_diff = {}

        self.setWindowTitle(EGuiParam.STR_TITLE.value)
        self.setGeometry(*EGuiParam.TI_INITIAL_WIN_SIZE.value)

        self.table_model = TableViewModel(str_path_to_report, parent=self)
        self.table_view = QTableView()
        self.table_view.setModel(self.table_model)

        # Main layout
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.table_view)
        layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        # Button layout
        horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addLayout(horizontalLayout)

        # Buttons
        button_viz_diff = QPushButton(EGuiParam.STR_VIZ_LABEL.value)
        button_viz_diff.setFixedSize(*EGuiParam.TI_BUTTON_SIZE.value)
        horizontalLayout.addWidget(button_viz_diff, alignment=Qt.AlignLeft)

        button_check = QPushButton(EGuiParam.STR_CHECK_LABEL.value)
        button_check.setFixedSize(*EGuiParam.TI_BUTTON_SIZE.value)
        horizontalLayout.addWidget(button_check)

        button_quit = QPushButton(EGuiParam.STR_QUIT_LABEL.value)
        button_quit.setFixedSize(*EGuiParam.TI_BUTTON_SIZE.value)
        horizontalLayout.addWidget(button_quit, alignment=Qt.AlignRight)

        button_update = QPushButton(EGuiParam.STR_UPDATE_LABEL.value)
        button_update.setFixedSize(*EGuiParam.TI_BUTTON_SIZE.value)

        horizontalLayout.addWidget(button_update)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        #référence aux action
        self.table_view.doubleClicked.connect(self.on_double_click)
        button_viz_diff.clicked.connect(self.open_meld)
        button_check.clicked.connect(self.reverse_all)
        button_update.clicked.connect(self.gen_diff_to_update)
        button_quit.clicked.connect(self.close)

    # Action des buttons
    # Generate dictionnary of diff
    @pyqtSlot()
    def gen_diff_to_update(self):
        ...
        self.close()

    # Open the meld widow
    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_double_click(self, index):#i_row, i_column):
        print("Double clicked ...")
        i_row = index.row()
        ...

    # Open the meld widow
    @pyqtSlot()
    def open_meld(self):
        ...

    # Reverse the selction of all checkbox
    @pyqtSlot()
    def reverse_all(self):
        ...

    def get_diff(self):
        return self.d_diff




def ask_diff(str_report_path, str_ref_path, str_ope_path):
    app = QApplication([])

    win = TableWidget(str_report_path, str_ref_path, str_ope_path)
    win.show()

    app.exec_()

    return win.get_diff()
```

My issue :

The signal "doubleClicked" doesn't work well for me. When I double click I'm getting the following error :

`TypeError: on_double_click() missing 1 required positional argument: 'index'`

The signal works well if I remove the argument "index" from my fonction... but in this case I can't do anything as I need the row index to know where the double click was done.

I did this based on [How to detect doubleClick in QTableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324005/how-to-detect-doubleclick-in-qtableview).

I also checked https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html even if it is for c++ instead of python. I'm not able to find anything about the QTableView's signals except the previous stackoverflow thread.

Can someone give me a clue about this ?

Comment: You're missing the slot signature argument. Change the `on_double_click` decorator to `@pyqtSlot(QModelIndex)` (QModelIndex is in the QtCore submodule, in case you're wondering), or just remove the decorator.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't the decorator were working like this

Comment: Please, can you explain yourself better? I've not understood what you meant in your last comment.

Comment: Ha right I forgot few words. "I didn't know that decorators are used to specify the provided args". I was just saying thanks :)

Comment: Ah, ok! You're welcome :-) I suggest you to read the official PyQt documentation about [signals and slots](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html), it will clarify many aspects.